# Trigger.io - do we know if have a plugin for card.io

Tags: trigger.io, card.io

I was wondering if there is a plugin to use card.io SDK to read any identification cards. Apparently there is one for phonegap like in here http://blog.lumberlabs.com/2012/04/new-cardio-phonegap-plugin.html

Comment: no shopping list questions please. Ask "how do I", not "is there a plugin to". The latter generates just a dump of links. Links rot.

Answer (score 1):

card.io is specialized for reading credit cards, not identity cards.

Looks like you can [write your own trigger.io plugins](http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2012/10/11/trigger-io-native-plugins-beta/). card.io has a very simple API, so wrapping it should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

I actually used card.io's SDK as an example in a native plugins webinar - see http://vimeo.com/66233891

There's not much code to get an integration up and running: I've put up my demo plugin [here](https://github.com/goodgravy/trigger.io-card.io) if you want to use that.